# Java: get days in first week of every 3 months in a given date range

Tags: java, date, calendar

For example: date range is from January 3rd, 2013 to October 3rd, 2013.
In above range, gets all the weekdays of first week of every 3 months. The result would be like this:

```
Thu Jan 03 00:00:00 ICT 2013
Fri Jan 04 00:00:00 ICT 2013
Sat Jan 05 00:00:00 ICT 2013
Sun Jan 06 00:00:00 ICT 2013
Mon Jan 07 00:00:00 ICT 2013
Mon Apr 01 00:00:00 ICT 2013
Tue Apr 02 00:00:00 ICT 2013
Wed Apr 03 00:00:00 ICT 2013
Thu Apr 04 00:00:00 ICT 2013
Fri Apr 05 00:00:00 ICT 2013
Sat Apr 06 00:00:00 ICT 2013
Sun Apr 07 00:00:00 ICT 2013
Mon Jul 01 00:00:00 ICT 2013
Tue Jul 02 00:00:00 ICT 2013
Wed Jul 03 00:00:00 ICT 2013
Thu Jul 04 00:00:00 ICT 2013
Fri Jul 05 00:00:00 ICT 2013
Sat Jul 06 00:00:00 ICT 2013
Sun Jul 07 00:00:00 ICT 2013
Tue Oct 01 00:00:00 ICT 2013
Wed Oct 02 00:00:00 ICT 2013
```

I have figured out a way to do it, but the code looks pretty ugly, so I wonder if there's any method which would be more elegant? Thanks for your help, I really appreciated it.

```
// set up the startCal and endCal
String fmtShowTime = "ddMMyy"; // TODO: move to configurations
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(fmtShowTime);
TimeZone defaultZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
sdf.setTimeZone(defaultZone);
String fromTime = "030113";
String toTime = "031013";
Date startDate = sdf.parse(fromTime);
Date endDate = sdf.parse(toTime);
Calendar startCal = Calendar.getInstance();
startCal.setTime(startDate);
Calendar endCal = Calendar.getInstance();
endCal.setTime(endDate);

// set up the condition for week and month
Integer week = Integer.parseInt("1"); // first week
Integer monthPeriod = Integer.parseInt("3"); // every 3 months
Integer counter = 0;

while (startCal.getTimeInMillis() < endCal.getTimeInMillis()) {
    if (startCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH) == week) {
        // check if the current day in loop is the day of first week in month
        if (monthPeriod == 1)  {
            // get for every month
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                    if (startCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH) != week || startCal.getTimeInMillis() == endCal.getTimeInMillis()) {
                        // break for case like Tuesday, January 8th (2nd Tuesday of January) or October 4th (range breached) 
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.println(startCal.getTime());
                    // move 1 more day
                    startCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            }
        }
        else {
            counter++;
            if (counter % monthPeriod == 1) {
                // I used counter mod monthPeriod to check if 3 months has passed in the loop, 1%3 = 1, 4%3 = 1 and so on
                for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                    if (startCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH) != week || startCal.getTimeInMillis() == endCal.getTimeInMillis()) {
                        // break for case like Tuesday, January 8th (2nd Tuesday of January) or October 4th (range breached)  
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.println(startCal.getTime());
                    // move 1 more day
                    startCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                }
            } else {
                //if it's the first week of a month but not 3 months has passed yet then I forward 7 days to pass the check for first week of the month
                startCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);
            }
        }
    }
    startCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
}
```

P.S Sorry if the code caused you eye-hurt, I know it's bad :)

Comment: while (startCal.getTimeInMillis() < endCal.getTimeInMillis()) <-- `Calendar` implements `Comparable`, therefore this can be written as `startCal.compareTo(endCal) < 0` (or even, since the method is there, `startCal.before(endCal)`

Comment: What if the range is from January 15th, 2013 to October 15th, 2013? Moreover, title says "2 months" whereas your question says "3 months".

Comment: @fge thanks for the your help. Using it would make it looks prettier a little bit.

Comment: @sp00m Sorry for the mistake between 2 or 3 months, however it does not matter since if you have a look at the code, there's a variable for defining the duration between months, $monthPeriod

if Jan 15th to Oct 15 then it would be start from Feb 1st, and next 3 months, May 1st and so on

Answer (score 0):

See my solution

```
    GregorianCalendar c1 = new GregorianCalendar(2013, 0, 3);
    GregorianCalendar c2 = new GregorianCalendar(2013, 9, 3);
    while (c1.before(c2)) {
        if (c1.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH) == 1 && c1.get(Calendar.MONTH) % 3 == 0) {
            System.out.println(c1.getTime());
        }
        c1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    }
```

Comment: By weekdays I meant that all days in the week, so I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: By weekdays I meant that all days in the week, so I'm sorry for the confusion. Your code is pretty clean and elegant. However, I wonder if it could be tweak for more general cases? For example, the start date is Feb 3rd? In this case, the condition `c1.get(Calendar.Month) % 3 == 0` would not be correct anymore, right? And also, the months period could be changeable too. Instead of every 3 months, it could be every 2 months, or 4 months etc. And the output above is missing the Mon Jan 07, because this is the first Monday of the first week of January?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear whether weekend days should or should not be included. However here is what I think will work based on my best guess at your requirements:

```
public class DateIntervalDayParser {

    // Test harness
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final int monthInterval = 3;
        final int daysFromStartOfMonth = 7;

        final DateIntervalDayParser parser = new DateIntervalDayParser();
        final List<Date> allWeekdays = parser.getWeekdays(
                new GregorianCalendar(2013, 0, 15), new GregorianCalendar(2013, 9, 15), monthInterval, daysFromStartOfMonth);

        for (final Date weekday : allWeekdays) {
            System.out.println(weekday);
        }
    }

    private List<Date> getWeekdays(final Calendar start, final Calendar end, final int monthInterval, int daysFromStartOfMonth)
    {
        // Start result list
        final List<Date> allWeekdays = new ArrayList<Date>();

        adjustStart(start, daysFromStartOfMonth);

        // Continue until start time has passed end time
        while (isMonthBeforeOrEqual(start, end)) {
            addWeekdays(allWeekdays, start, daysFromStartOfMonth);

            // Add month interval
            // NOTE: always set day of month to 1st day of month after 1st month
            start.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            start.add(Calendar.MONTH, monthInterval);

            // If we are in the last month, set last day of month maximum to last
            // months day if it is less than a week from the start of the month
            if (start.get(Calendar.YEAR) == end.get(Calendar.YEAR)
                    && start.get(Calendar.MONTH) == end.get(Calendar.MONTH)
                    && end.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) < daysFromStartOfMonth) {
                daysFromStartOfMonth = end.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            }
        }

        return allWeekdays;
    }

    private void adjustStart(final Calendar start, int daysFromStartOfMonth) {
        // If day of month in 1st month has passed max days from start of month,
        // start from the start of the next month
        if (start.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) > daysFromStartOfMonth) {
            start.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            start.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        }
    }

    private boolean isMonthBeforeOrEqual(final Calendar start, final Calendar end) {
        boolean beforeOrEqual = false;
        final int startYear = start.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        final int endYear = end.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        if (startYear < endYear) {
            beforeOrEqual = true;
        } else if (startYear == endYear) {
            beforeOrEqual = start.get(Calendar.MONTH) <= end.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        }
        return beforeOrEqual;
    }

    private void addWeekdays(final List<Date> days, final Calendar calendar, final int daysFromStartOfMonth) {
        // Add dates until day of month is exceeded
        int dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        while (dayOfMonth <= daysFromStartOfMonth) {
            days.add(calendar.getTime());

            // Increment
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            dayOfMonth++;
        }
    }
}
```

On a general note. I would envourage you to break down your logic into smaller easier to manage methods. Not only will you be able to re-use such code easier, but it will reduce its complexity making maintenance easier.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. My problem is, given a date range, a months period, and a set of week days (Monday -> Sunday), I need to print all the days that satisfied the conditions: they are in the date range, they are one of the week days and they are separated by the months period. The above example are getting all from Monday to Sunday of the first week of every 3 months. The code I wrote could be applied to getting Monday to Sunday of the third week of every 2 months for another example. So could I applied the above code for getting the required results of this example?